# C# comparing reference and value types with null

Tags: c#

How does it work?

```cs
          public class Node
            {
              Node Left ;
              Node Right ;
            }
...
            var a = new Node();
            var b = new Node();
            if (a.Right == b.Right == null) // <- compiles and resharper says it's always false
            {
            }

            var aa = 1;
            var bb = 2;
            if (aa == bb == 0) // doesn't compile Cannot apply operator '==' to operands of type 'bool' and 'int'
            {

            }
```

Why do multiple comparands work with 'Node' and doesn't work with 'Int'?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile for me, I get the same CS0019 error "Operator `==` cannot be applied..."  for both `if` statements. Using C# 7.3.

Comment: If your first `if` statement *does* compile, then it means your `Node` type is somehow implicitly convertible to (or from) `Boolean`. Are you missing code from your post?

Comment: reason is simple. you can compare object against null, but not int against boolean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, you can't compare like this, ever...

In regards to `if (a.Right == b.Right == null)`

It compiles because you can compare a non-nullable *value types* with `null` and it's always false.

1. `a.Right == b.Right // bool`
2. `bool == null //will be lifted and always equal false (see below)`

To know the reason why you'll have to visit the specs and understand lifted operators

**12.4.8 Lifted operators**

> Lifted operators permit predefined and user-defined operators that
>   operate on non-nullable value types to also be used with nullable
>   forms of those types
>
> - For the equality operators `==` `!=`
>
> **a lifted form of an operator exists if the operand types are both
>   non-nullable value types and if the result type is bool**. The lifted
>   form is constructed by adding a single ? modifier to each operand
>   type. The lifted operator considers two null values equal, **and a null
>   value unequal to any non-null value**. If both operands are non-null,
>   the lifted operator unwraps the operands and applies the underlying
>   operator to produce the bool result.

In regards to `if(aa == bb == 0)` you can't compare `bool` with an `int`, there is no implicit conversion to bool

1. `aa == bb // bool`
2. `bool == 0 // there is no implicit conversion to bool`

Answer (score 1):

An expression like

```
a == b == c
```

is interpreted as

```
(a == b) == c
```

so first `a == b` is evaluated and returns either `true` or `false`, a boolean.
Then `someBool == c` is evaluated. If c is 0, then you are comparing a bool against an int, which leads to your compile error.

However if c is `null`, then both that null and that "someBool" are <s>promoted</s> lifted to a `Nullable<bool>` (or `bool?`), so they *can* be compared. But of course a true or false is never equal to `(bool?)null`, which is what Resharper says.

So you cannot take this shortcut and will have to write it as

```
(a == c) && (b == c)
```

Or in your case:

```
if (a.Right == null && b.Right == null) ...
if (aa == 0 && bb == 0) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why do multiple comparands work with 'Node' and doesn't work with
>   'Int'?
>
> A) *I guess you should be asking why it works with Null and not Int values. In your example above Node is a reference type and integer 0 is a value type*. *Read details below*

All *Value Types* can be compared to `null` because they are convertible to nullable and `null` is the default value assigned to a *Reference Types*

[Value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types) types include : *Bool, Integers, Floating points, char*

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) types include : *Class, string, objects, interface*

*Valid Cases:*

```
bool a =true;
if(a == null) //a is converted to a Nullable Boolean and then compared with null`

if(a.Right==b.Right==null) //First 2 statements are evaluated to boolean, which is converted to a Nullable Boolean and then compared with null`

int i=5;
if(i==null) // i is converted to a Nullable int and then compared with null, which always ends up false as the value of i is 5

Nullable<int> ii = 5;
if(ii==null) // ii being a nullable int is compared with null, there will not be any warnings indicated by the compiler as it know before hand that ii has a chance of being null

int a =5; int b=4;
if(a==b) // Valid, because your comparing 2 Integers are equal
```

*Invalid Cases:*

```
int a =5; int b=4;
if(a==b==0) // First 2 statements evaulate to a boolean and a boolean is evaluated to a Integer, the compiler fails to understand how to convert a Boolean to Int and hence the error 

if(a==true) // same as above, compiler fails to compare an integer to a boolean and results in an error
```